# Need help understanding hypothesis tests in multivariate statistics

Tags: self-study, multivariate-analysis

I'm not really sure where to begin with this question, and I'm not sure if I am supplying all the resources necessary to answer this question, so just let me know and I will update. I'm going to copy and paste the question, then write up the relevant information needed as the question progresses.

$\textit{Test for independence}$. If the $p$ variables in a MVN sample are independently distributed
then

$ \Sigma = diag(\sigma_{11},...,\sigma_{pp})$

Show that the m.l.e. of $\sigma_{ii}$ is $s_{ii}$ the i
th diagonal element of the sample covariance matrix $S$:
Hence that

$\hat{\Sigma} = diag(s_{11},...s_{pp})= D$

Now, we are given earlier on that

$S = 
\begin{pmatrix}
91.48&66.88\\
66.88&96.78\\
\end{pmatrix}$

So where do I begin?

Comment: Hint: the off-diagonal elements are covariances. Independence has implications for what those covariances should be.

Comment: independence implies uncorrelated implying covariance = 0, hence all the off diagonal elements are going to be 0 if our P variables are independent.